# Which transaction will go 1st

Tags: nonce

I was wondering, If I have created two transactions in Ethereum

1st one with x nonce and gas fee 5 gwei.

2nd one with x+1 nonce (as it is automatically assigned by metamask) but with a gas fee 6 gwei.

Current Gas fee is 8 Gwei , When the network will adjust and lower down the Gas fee , which transaction ll go 1st?

Answer (score 1):

Take the nonce like order of transactions execution. Let's take that the current gas price is 10 and if we submit a transaction with nonce 5 and signed with 5 gwei and another transaction with nonce 6 and 500 gwei, then it does that matter that you signed the 2nd transaction with gas price 50 times higher than the current gas price, it won't execute until the transaction before is approved on the blockchain.

Comment: I Agree and I have observed that on metamask the 2nd transaction always queued

Answer (score 0):

The transaction that is mined must have a nonce that is exactly one greater than the previously mined transaction's nonce. The second one won't confirm until the first one has confirmed

[Transaction nonce management](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7157/transaction-nonce-management?rq=1)